# SQL UTC date instead of SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

Working on the following query.

```
SELECT MIN(departure_date), ch_invoice.invoice_id
FROM ch_invoice
INNER JOIN ch_trip
ON ch_invoice.invoice_id = ch_trip.invoice_id
WHERE departure_date < SYSDATE
AND service_rendered = 0
AND paid = 1
Group By ch_invoice.invoice_id
```

Since the database that it is hitting may be in a location where the date hasn't changed yet, and we are using UTC as a standard for our dates, is it possible to replace SYSDATE with something like UTCDATE? I just need to know what day UTC is currently at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As AntDC suggested, you can use [the `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions186.htm). That converts a 'datetime with time zone' from whatever time zone it is in to UTC.

SYSDATE doesn't have a time zone. If you passed that in then it would be implicitly converted to the system time zone, so it would work, but you can use SYSTIMESTAMP instead as that is already zone-aware.

You said in a comment that you want the date, but all Oracle dates have a time component; you can get the result as a date *type* with the time set to midnight (which makes sense for the comparison you're doing) with [`TRUNC()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm):

```
select systimestamp,
  sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as utctime,
  trunc(sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)) as utcdate
from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                     UTCTIME                   UTCDATE
-------------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------
2016-04-08 17:18:27.352 +01:00   2016-04-08 16:18:27.352   2016-04-08 00:00:00
```

That's running on a server in the UK, so the local time is BST.

Since that doesn't involve a day change, the effect can be demonstrated using the session time instead of the server time:

```
alter session set time_zone = '+12:00';

select current_timestamp,
  sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp) as utctime,
  trunc(sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp)) as utcdate
from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                UTCTIME                   UTCDATE
-------------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------
2016-04-09 04:23:17.910 +12:00   2016-04-08 16:23:17.910   2016-04-08 00:00:00
```

My session time is 2016-04-09, but it still finds the UTC date as 2016-04-08.

(To be clear, I am *not* suggesting you switch to using `current_timestamp` or `current_date`; I'm using those instead of `systimestamp` and `sysdate` purely as a demo).

Comment: Your edit anticipated my question and answered it. Thank you! That is very clear. I believe this achieves what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can I pass sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) as utctime in values to my insert query ? When I am trying to achieve that it gives me ORA-00917: missing comma.

Comment: @Dish - if you have a new problem, ask a new question. But if you've put that in the `values(...)`  clause then you just need to remove the `as utctime` part.

Comment: @AlexPoole It is not a new problem if you read closely. I was able to proceed without any new solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(departure_date)UTC_SYS, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. Can you explain what it is doing?

Comment: http://psoug.org/definition/SYS_EXTRACT_UTC.htm

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC is a function which returns the UTC date for a given date

Comment: Shouldn't you be converting the system time, not the table time, i.e. SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)? If you call it on `departure_date` and that is a DATE type it'll be implicitly converted to the system time zone first, which could give odd results, since it sounds like the stored value is supposed to already be UTC.

Comment: @AntDC It seems like that code will extract GMT from a datetime with a timezone. I don't need the GMT time, I simply need to know which day GMT is currently on. Is it possible to do something like GETGMTDATE in SQL Oracle?